# Получение имени станции от Яндекс API

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-jsapi, yandex-geocoding-api

```
var myGeocoder = ymaps.geocode(coords, {kind: 'metro'});
```

Собственно я знаю как получить ближайшую станцию метро, но вот в че проблема. Как получить её имя?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var myGeocoder = ymaps.geocode(coords, {kind: 'metro'}).then(function(res) {
  var nearest = res.geoObjects.get(0); 
  name = nearest.properties.get('name');
});
```